# Issue with WordPress Text widget in IE8 only

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, widget

Hi I have a text widget with one line of text "Connect with me on Facebook" that displays at the bottom of this page http://contemporaryinteriordesigns.com.au/.  It displays on 1 line for every browser except for IE8.
Does anyone know why IE8 is creating a line break and how I could fix it?
Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 0):

I think IE8 is acting weird because you're styling the text in the `div` selector. Try wrapping that text into a tag:

```
<div class="textwidget">
    <a><img/></a>
    <p>Connect with me on Facebook</p> <!-- Wrap it in a paragraph -->
</div>
```

***The `<div>` tag defines a division or a section in an HTML document.*** and ***The `<p>` tag defines a paragraph***. Wrapping the text in `<p>` is more semantically correct. Then style the `<p>` till you get it right. Since I can't edit the code and I'm testing with IETester I can't try it out.

Comment: Hi good point. I tried adding in the <p> tags, but it hasn't helped. Looking at the code with inspect element it doesn't seem to be reading the <p> tags from the text widget. Any ideas on what else I can try?